# Doubt regarding Views

Tags: android

Suppose MyView is a class derived from View and mView is a variable of type MyView. 
How to display mView when the android app is started?

Answer (score 2):

*Short answer:* Like any other `View`, use `setContentView(View v)`, although you will probably want to add it to a `ViewGroup` first (usually one of the many layout classes).

*Long answer:* Rather than answering the basics in each of your questions, I believe the best the community can do for you here is to point you to the sources to learn android basic programming. One of the best sources to start is the android.com website itself. Please, take your time to read the **Android Developers Guide** (link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html).

Also, there are several questions here in SO that link to many resources to learn:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456733/how-to-learn-android
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949818/how-can-i-learn-android
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869338/where-to-start-to-learn-android
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475152/how-can-i-learn-android
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114287/good-book-for-beginning-android-development

Also, in order to avoid getting close votes in your questions, please take a moment to read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [these tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a `LinearLayout` in your `main.xml`.

In the `onCreate` method, you will have:

```
MyView mView = new MyView(this);
mView.setId(ID_OF_YOUR_CUSTOM_VIEW);
//modify next line as needed
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
mView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ID_OF_YOUR_LAYOUT);
layout.addView(mView);
```